# Node js trying to send an image from a client to another client through server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, drawing

I am using node js, express, and javascript. I am drawing a picture on the client side with a canvas. I want to send that image to another user. But so far when I am sending it to the server and the server sends it to that specific client I get a broken image icon. How do I go about this? Do I have to take another approach? Do I convert the file? Any help please and I am open to answering any further questions, Thanks in advance!

CLIENT.JS

```
<img id="canvasimg"  style="display:none;">
<img id="canvasimgSENTBYSERVER"  style="display:none;">


var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

//create a drawing blah blah blah

function sendDrawing()
{
 document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.border = "2px solid";
 var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
 document.getElementById("canvasimg").src = dataURL;
 socket.emit('image', dataURL);
}
socket.on('send image to client', function(dataURL1)
{
     document.getElementById("canvasimgSENTBYSERVER").src = dataURL1;
     document.getElementById("canvasimgSENTBYSERVER").style.display = "inline";
     console.log("drawn image test");
     $canvasimg.show();
     $canvasimgSENTBYSERVER.show();

});
```

SERVER.js

```
socket.on('image', function (dataUrl) 
{
  user1.emit('send image to client',{user:users[users.indexOf(socket.username)],dataUrl});

});
```

Comment: Anything in the Browser Developer Tools Console to indicate a problem?

Comment: @JaromandaX the console says this GET http://localhost:3000/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)

Comment: oh, that means `dataURL1` is an OBJECT not a string .. console.log(dataURL1) - what do you see - you probably want `dataURL1.dataUrl` for the `.src` - as you are sending `{user: , dataUrl: }` object .... can you send Objects in .emit? or should you be using JSON.stringify and JSON.parse?

Comment: @JaromandaX you my friend, are a a genius thank you.

Comment: A genius would've spotted it straight away :p

Comment: Why did you delete this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48857413/nodejs-how-to-run-method-only-when-you-type-something-in-the-url/48859111#48859111 when I wrote an answer showing you exactly how to solve your issue?  So, you're saying that I should never bother to write an answer to your questions?  Because once you have the answer, you'll just delete the question?  The proper procedure here is to either accept the answer (by clicking the checkmark to the left of it) or to comment if it isn't quite yet what you were looking for or it isn't working for you.